# Unable to query data using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I  have three tables course, texts and book_adoption. I am getting an error when i am executing the following code-

```
connect();
            string qstr = "select course_id, book_isbn, book_title from texts natural join Book_Adoption natural join course where exists(select count(book_isbn) from Book_Adoption natural join course group by dept having count(course_id)>1) order by book_title";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(qstr, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "course");
            //da.Fill(ds, "Texts");
            //da.Fill(ds, "Book_Adoption");
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["course_id"].ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["book_isbn"].ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["book_title"].ToString());
            }
```

I am getting an error in the line `da.Fill(ds, "texts");`
When I am not using a natural join and doing a simple query, I am getting the correct output. WHat is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please include details of the actual error you're getting.

Comment: OleDbException was unhandled

IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: if dt is DataTable couldnt you just use da.Fill(dt); ?

Comment: when i do that i am getting this error- Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataTable

Comment: What is about the joins that causes problems? I'm not familiar with natural joins but is there a case of primary keys not being set? If you run the query on Access directly does it work?

Comment: i edited my query and did a simple natural join which is working in ms access but when i write the same query in c# it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be this bit of your SQL query

```
(select count(book_isbn) from Book_Adoption
```

You're selecting a count not a column and this may be causing a problem because it doesn't know the column name.
See [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/900041-oledbexception-ierrorinfo-getdescription-failed-e_fail-0x80004005) for a similar scenario.

Comment: Following on from the answer Nanhydrin makes. Can you run this query in Access with no errors: "select course_id, book_isbn, book_title from texts natural join Book_Adoption natural join course where exists(select count(book_isbn) from Book_Adoption natural join course group by dept having count(course_id)>1) order by book_title"